# Unable to unhook events of backgroundworker of windows forms (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I am trying to unregister events by passing delgates as parameters to a function that unhooks them, they not exactly getting unhooked.

```
    public void registerHandlers(RunWorkerCompleted backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted, DoWork backgroundWorker1_dowork, ProgressChanged backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_dowork;
        this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;  
    }

    public void unregisterHandlers(RunWorkerCompleted backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted, DoWork backgroundWorker1_dowork, ProgressChanged backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork -= backgroundWorker1_dowork;
        this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged -= backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;  
    }

    private void buuton1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registerHandlers(this.worker1_RunWorkerCompleted, this.worker1_doWork, this.worker1_progressChangedHandler);
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void buuton2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        registerHandlers(this.worker2_RunWorkerCompleted, this.worker2_doWork, this.worker2_progressChangedHandler);
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    // ..

    private void worker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // ..
        }
        finally
        {
            unregisterHandlers(this.worker1_RunWorkerCompleted, this.worker1_doWork, this.worker1_progressChangedHandler);    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

to:

```
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

That is a mistake in your code. (And similarly, the two next to it.)

But, frankly, it's not clear what's happening. If you don't call the the `BackgroundWorker` with the `RunWorkerAsync();` command – it's not going to run even if it's hooked up. So what is it that you see happening more than once? Is it the `RunWorkerCompleted` that is getting called twice when *one* `BackgroundWorker` finishes?

If you just want to keep the `BackgroundWorker` in order to use it again – you don't *need* to unregister anything. Nothing will fire until you'll call `RunWorkerAsync();` again, and then – you'll *want* the events registered.

Comment: +1 - Good point on not needing the hooking/unhooking process.

Comment: THough I changed it as u said its still not unhooking the events

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is because you are instantiating a new delegate and trying to remove that. However, that delegate was never added to the event in the first place. When working with events where I wish to hook/unhook, I use the method itself. So in your case, I would do something like:

```
// ...

// Hook up to event
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

// ...

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Unhook from event
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;

    // ...
}
```

Note: By delegate, I am referring to your event handler instantiations (i.e. `new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(...)`).

Comment: Define "didn't work". Do you mean the event handler gets called again *after* unhooking it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding hooking to the event more than once? I would suggest putting a break point on both the hook and unhook lines and step through your code to see how many times each gets hit. Either that, or print out a message to the output window to signify which statement the code is executing.

Comment: @user186246 Did you by any chance add _all_ of Slade's code? Don't add the line with the `+=`, only the line with the `-=`.

Comment: That's a good point - the `+=` part of the code example was just to highlight that somewhere else in the code the event handler is being hooked up to the event in the way shown.

Comment: @Slade: I am sure I am no where hooking handler for twice

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the event handler? It may also be worth writing a very small test project using the `BackgroundWorker` and hooking/unhooking the events to repro your scenario. It may help to identify the cause of the issue.

Comment: @user186246 Make sure you're using Slade's code and _not_ `-= new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted)` - You don't want to unhook a _new_ "event-handler".

Comment: @ispiro : I have added the code where I am registering handlers in the main post

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to add another answer to this, as the comment stream on the previous post is getting rather lengthy and editing my current answer would extend it too much.

I am a little confused by your code - I don't know whether you have changed it since the original post or not. I have a few points to say on the matter:

1. Make sure when you are hooking/unhooking event handlers to/from events that you do not call `new` on the delegate. Simply use the name of the method (as stated in the answer above - see below).
2. If you are not using `registerHandlers(...)` and `unregisterHandlers(...)` elsewhere, then I don't see the need to have to pass in the delegates, especially if the methods are in the same class as those delegates. Surely, the method *can* be allowed to know of those delegates and add/remove them accordingly.
3. You originally stated that your method `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` was executed more than once, even after unhooking from the event. From what I can see in your edited code, that is entirely plausible since you are not unhooking that event handler anywhere. Instead, you are unhooking the handler `workerCompleted`. Also, the fact that you have named the local variable (inside `unregisterHandlers(...)`) for the `RunWorkerCompleted` delegate the same as the actual method, may cause confusion for the compiler (I'm not certain of this, but it would seem likely to me).

So, in light of those points, I would change the above code to something more like this:

```
private BackgroundWorker mBackgroundWorker; // Instantiated elsewhere

#region Registration

private void RegisterHandlers()
{
    // Hook up to the background worker events
    mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += mBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    mBackgroundWorker.DoWork += mBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
    mBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += mBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
}

private void UnregisterHandlers()
{
    // Unhook from the background worker events
    mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= mBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    mBackgroundWorker.DoWork -= mBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
    mBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged -= mBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
}

#endregion

#region Event Handlers

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterHandlers();

    // Start the background worker
    mBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void mBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        UnregisterHandlers();
    }
}

private void mBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}

private void mBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}

#endregion
```

Note that the names of methods and variables do not exactly match your own, so you will need to be careful to change them accordingly. If you pay careful attention, however, to how the code is written, you should see what I mean with regards to the hooking/unhooking of event handlers.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I have written a small test app to manually test your issue, and following the points I have made so far I have no issues. The source code to my test app can be found on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/RiWuPqhb). The results printed in my output window in Visual Studio are:

```
Worker 1: Do Work
Worker 1: Run Worker Completed
Worker 2: Do Work
Worker 2: Run Worker Completed
Worker 1: Do Work
Worker 1: Run Worker Completed
Worker 2: Do Work
Worker 2: Run Worker Completed
```

The above output is as a result of clicking the worker buttons in the sequence: Worker 1, Worker 2, Worker 1, Worker 2.

**EDIT 2**

In response to you trying to control the event handlers of a designer-generated `BackgroundWorker`; I would imagine the following is occurring in your code:

1. WinForms designer-generated code instantiates `backgroundWorker1`.
2. WinForms designer-generated code hooks event handlers to `backgroundWorker1` (handler count: 1).
3. User clicks `button1`.
4. Your code hooks event handlers to `backgroundWorker1` (handler count: 2). *This is where you are going to get multiple hook ups.*

If this *is* what is going on, then you should be able to stop the designer-generated code from hooking to events by deleting any event handlers specified in the Events part of the Form Designer Property Grid.

Comment: I would like to change the event handlers based on the situation, so I have added parameters to the registerHandlers() and unregisterHandlers() methods.

Comment: @user186246 Ok, that makes sense. However, I would make sure you name your parameters differently to any methods, just to be sure there can be no confusion.

Comment: Do you know why it is failing to unhook?

Comment: @user186246 If you have changed your code to represent the changes I have highlighted, then I'm afraid I'm all out of suggestions. If you want, you can upload your entire code file to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com) and I will take a look.

Comment: It is failing if when I add parameters to the register and unregister methods. The parameter( i.e delegates hold the same method which I am passing) But still why are they failing?

Comment: @user186246 Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you edit your original post to show what you mean?

Comment: One more point is I have instantiated BackgroundWorker in the designer code but added/removed events dynamically from the code. I have used backgroundworker component of windows forms

Comment: @user186246 Both of the `BackgroundWorker`'s?

Comment: @user186246 See extended answer.

Comment: @user186246 My mistake. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Slade: No event handlers are hooked in the designer code. They were registered dynamically when the user clicks button

Comment: @user186246 The only thing I can suggest now then, is if you post your code on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com) or upload it to [MegaUpload](http://megaupload.com), for example, and I'll try to compile and run it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

try to inherit from the BackgroundWorker class and implement IDisposable interface on it.. and try unregistering event in Dispose() method..

Regards.

Comment: I am not disposing the backgroundworker, reusing the component by registering and unregistering it's event handlers.